# Problema caracteres java en Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, caracteres

al importar un proyecto en eclipse me salen errores en los caracteres de mi archivo java. Pongo un ejemplo, alguien sabe la solución?

`System.out.println("ERROR:al cerrar la conexiÃƒÂ³n");`

Comment: intenta ver la codificacion y que esté en UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

Esto esta relacionado a la codificación de tus archivos, en el caso de Eclipse puedes evitar este problema cambiando la codificación a `UTF-8`, lo puedes realizar de esta forma:

`Preferences` > `General` > `Workspace` 
Aquí debes seleccionar `UTF-8` como el encoding para tus archivos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FwrkAdv_encoding.htm

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso tuve que seleccionar "ISO-8859-1" en Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> "File text encoding", Other.